# Each loop in test forgeting variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, loops

I have a problem testing my rails app. I have this code for my tests:

```
describe Categoria do

  let(:categoria) { FactoryGirl.create(:categoria) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "agregar campos" do
    before { @campo = categoria.campos.build(nombre: "campo1", tipo_campo: "check_box") }

    it { @campo.should be_valid }
    it { @campo.should respond_to :nombre }
    it { @campo.should respond_to :tipo_campo }
    it { @campo.should respond_to :requerido }

    describe "valores válidos" do
      valores = %w[texto texto_extenso numero decimal check_box]
      valores.each do |valido|
        @campo.tipo_campo = valido
        @campo.should be_valid
      end    
    end
  end
end
```

If I run the tests without the block "valores válidos" an all the other tests pass, but when I run all the tests, I get this error:

```
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Exception encountered: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `tipo_campo=' for nil:NilClass>
backtrace:
/home/alejo/proyectos/lachiquitienda/spec/models/categoria_spec.rb:38:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/alejo/proyectos/lachiquitienda/spec/models/categoria_spec.rb:37:in `each'
/home/alejo/proyectos/lachiquitienda/spec/models/categoria_spec.rb:37:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
/home/alejo/proyectos/lachiquitienda/spec/models/categoria_spec.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
/home/alejo/proyectos/lachiquitienda/spec/models/categoria_spec.rb:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
/home/alejo/proyectos/lachiquitienda/spec/models/categoria_spec.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:11:in `run_tests'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
/home/alejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'
/home/alejo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform_without_block'
/home/alejo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1508:in `perform'
/home/alejo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1586:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
/home/alejo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `loop'
/home/alejo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `block in main_loop'
[Finished in 5.9s]
```

Why is @campo nil iniside the each loop?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not inside the context of a test when you are trying to access it.

All your other tests are marked with `it { }` blocks (rspec will also accept `specify { }` blocks) - your loop does not define any tests.

Try something like the following:

```
describe "valores válidos" do
  valores = %w[texto texto_extenso numero decimal check_box]
  valores.each do |valido|
    it "allows the value #{valido}" do # put your own translation in here!
      @campo.tipo_campo = valido
      @campo.should be_valid
    end
  end    
end
```

Now your assignments are inside tests and the variable `@campo` will be defined.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. This is why I love stackoverflow